# No se puede establecer una conexión con jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

Buen día a todos, tengo el siguiente error, al tratar de conectar la Base de Datos de Oracle 11.2 con el IDE NetBeans 8.0.2 me salta este error, he estado buscando en internet la forma de arreglarlo o si era un error mío pero no he podido encontrar información.
Hay alguna forma de solucionar este error? Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Yordy, pordrias agregar que Driver y cual versión de JDK utilizas.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, tenía un error con el IDE. La base de datos de Oracle no la reconocía por alguna razón, pero instalando la versión 8.1 pude hacer el enlace.